# Given an adjacency matrix, How to draw a graph with matplotlib?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, graph-drawing

I have an undirected graph described by its adjacency matrix (a numpy array) and I want to plot it, with vertices placed in a n-regular polygon. This code works:

```
n = adyacency_mathix.shape[0]
axis = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, n, endpoint=False)
x, y = np.cos(axis), np.sin(axis)
for i in xrange(n):
    for j in xrange(i + 1, n):
        if self.matrix[i, j] == 1:
            pyplot.plot((x[i], x[j]), (y[i], y[j]), color = 'blue')
pyplot.show()
```

but can be optimized.

Comment: What is the question? Please edit you post to actually provide a clear problem description and a question. See [ask] and [mcve]. Otherwise the question needs to be closed.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I want and optimized version of this code

Comment: @DiegoSilvera Define "optimized". You can optimize for a large number of metrics. If you're concerned about time, the drawing will take far longer than the computation anyway, but profile it for yourself to identify the bottlenecks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may be interested in the popular `networkx` project, if you're interested in simply reducing the amount of code you write.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

# Generating sample data
G = nx.florentine_families_graph()
adjacency_matrix = nx.adjacency_matrix(G)

# The actual work
# You may prefer `nx.from_numpy_matrix`.
G2 = nx.from_scipy_sparse_matrix(adjacency_matrix)
nx.draw_circular(G2)
plt.axis('equal')
```

[image: florentine circular graph]

Disclaimer: I am a contributor to `networkx`.

Comment: Thank you!! Is there a way to label the vertices?

Comment: There sure is. The documentation for [`draw_circular`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_circular.html#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_circular) points out that you can use the keyword args from [`draw_networkx`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx.html#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx), one of which would be `with_labels=True`.

Comment: Hi, could you be so kind and update your answer since it seems that networkx has changed I currently receive executing "nx.adjacency_matrix(G)" No module named 'scipy' so I guess the whole function is deprecated?

Comment: Hi, that doesn't mean it's deprecated. You just need to install `scipy` also, so that `networkx` can import and use it. I've found the easiest way to do this is with an environment manager like `conda`. You can in one line do `conda create --name myenvironment python=3.7 scipy networkx`.

Comment: In networkx 3.0, the function is `nx.from_scipy_sparse_array(adjacency_matrix)`