# How do I plot a graph using a 2d list

Tags: python-3.x, list, graph, networkx

[Given an adjacency matrix, How to draw a graph with matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44271504/given-an-adjacency-matrix-how-to-draw-a-graph-with-matplotlib)

I referred to this but I am getting an error

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'

I have a 2d list with same number of rows and column

```
class Graph:
def __init__(self,Vertices):
    self.V=Vertices
    self.graph=[]
    self.path=[]
    for i in range(self.V):
        l=[]
        for j in range(self.V):
            l.append(0)
        self.graph.append(l)
```

This is what I am doing and for drawing I used the link mentioned above.

Am I missing something or what should I do ?

Comment: If you are free to use any library, I recommend you to take a look at [`networkx`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/tutorial.html), which you already linked accidentally

Comment: @Sparky05 i am using networkx the link i mentioned above has an answer code anywho I was able to debug it thanks